# regex remove specific text inside tag Notepad++

Tags: javascript, html, regex, xml, notepad++

Hello i'm a bit new to coding and trying to understand how regular expressions works,

so i'm working on an XML file with products and want to delete specific text inside a tag. From the example below:

```html
<descr>&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;P&gt;SOME RANDOM TEXT&lt;/P&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;br/&gt;</descr>
```

i want to remove this part:

```html
&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;
```

cause its interfering with the text format.
This may happen multiple times within the  tag, so i want to remove it every time.
Can i do this with a regex in Notepad++ ?

Comment: i want to remove the specific text inside the <descr> tag in every product in my file. The products have many other tags as well, which should remain intact. Can i search inside a specific tag with the normal replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do your replace with this regex:

```
(<descr>[\s\S]*?)&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;\/P&gt;([\s\S]*?<\/descr>)
```

Replacing it by:

```
$1 SUCCESS $2
```

I used as input:

```
<descr>&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;P&gt;SOME RANDOM TEXT&lt;/P&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;br/&gt;</descr>

<other>&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;P&gt;SOME RANDOM TEXT&lt;/P&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;br/&gt;</other>

<descr>&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;P&gt;SOME RANDOM TEXT&lt;/P&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;br/&gt;</descr>
```

And it became:

```
<descr>&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;P&gt;SOME RANDOM TEXT&lt;/P&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
 SUCCESS &lt;br/&gt;</descr>

<other>&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;P&gt;SOME RANDOM TEXT&lt;/P&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;br/&gt;</other>

<descr>&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;P&gt;SOME RANDOM TEXT&lt;/P&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
 SUCCESS &lt;br/&gt;</descr>
```

Image:

[image]

Explaining the regex:

```
(                                 # start of group 1
    <descr>                           # match the open tag
    [\s\S]                            # space or non-space characters = anything
          *?                          # the minimum amount till the next match
)                                 # end of group 1
&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;\/P&gt;    # your pattern, please note I had to escape the slash
(                                 # start of group 2
    [\s\S]                            # space or non-space characters = anything
          *?                          # the minimum amount till the next match
    <\/descr>                         # the closing tag, again look the escaped slash
)                                 # end of group 2
```

And the replace:

```
$1 SUCCESS $2                     # $1 stores the value matched by the group 1
                                  # $2 stores the value matched by the group 2
                                  # The text " SUCCESS " was an example, it could be empty
```

Comment: That was brilliant! Thank you very much Guedes!

Comment: Thx a lot for the explanation below, it helps me to understand better that :)

Comment: Glad to see it helped :)

Comment: If there are tags other than `descr` in between that contain `&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;` those substrings will also get removed. The solution is not valid for the current task.